# Permissions are missing in Get User Access Token (Graph API)

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I m new to Meta Dev platform, and just want to send posts to my personal feed with python facebook-sdk.
Not sure if I need to add publish_actions permission along with public_profile. publish_actions is not in the permission list, so I cant select it. Python script with a token with only public_profile permission fails to run with the following error:

```
Error occurred: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and 
either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement 
and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, 
requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with 
sufficient administrative permission
```

Do I need Login from Products for the app? I dont have website that could handle URL validation and redirection. Even if I add Login, publish_actions still not present in Graph API explorer permission list.

Code:

```
import facebook

def post_to_feed(access_token, message):
    try:
        # Create a Facebook Graph API object
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

        # Post to your personal feed
        graph.put_object("me", "feed", message=message)

        print("Post successfully posted to your personal feed.")
    except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace 'your_access_token' with your actual access token obtained from Facebook Graph API Explorer or elsewhere
    access_token = "xxxxxxxx"

    # Message you want to post
    message = "Hello, world! This is my test post."

    # Call the function to post to your feed
    post_to_feed(access_token, message)
```

Comment: Posting to user profiles via API is not possibly any more, that has been removed _ages_ ago. And the permission `publish_actions` together with it.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Can someone's post text and the like numbers of that post be grabbed via API? Assuming post ID and user ID are known.

Comment: Access to user posts always requires the user's consent (`user_posts` permission.)

Comment: I'm learning now Graph API Explorer, and below more-less grabs what I want:
`https://grapf.facebook.com/v19.0/me?fields=id,name,posts,likes`
However, it doesnt show firends' posts, comments I liked. It only shows pages I liked. It doesnt even show my self-likes. Is there a way to get those likes too?
Not sure if I understood correctly your last comment, but should I ask for access token from someone whose likes I want to get with the API?

Comment: Unless a friend posted on _your_ timeline, you don't just get their posts. They would have to log in to your app and grant it permission first. And there is no endpoint that would return all your post likes.